# What makes erlang scalable?

Tags: erlang

I am working on an article describing fundamentals of technologies used by scalable systems. I have worked on Erlang before in a self-learning excercise. I have gone through several articles but have not been able to answer the following questions:

1. What is in the implementation of Erlang that makes it scalable? What makes it able to run concurrent processes more efficiently than technologies like Java?
2. What is the relation between functional programming and parallelization? With the declarative syntax of Erlang, do we achieve run-time efficiency?
3. Does process state not make it heavy? If we have thousands of concurrent users and spawn and equal number of processes as gen_server or any other equivalent pattern, each process would maintain a state. With so many processes, will it not be a drain on the RAM?
4. If a process has to make DB operations and we spawn multiple instances of that process, eventually the DB will become a bottleneck. This happens even if we use traditional models like Apache-PHP. Almost every business application needs DB access. What then do we gain from using Erlang?
5. How does process restart help? A process crashes when something is wrong in its logic or in the data. OTP allows you to restart a process. If the logic or data does not change, why would the process not crash again and keep crashing always?

Most articles sing praises about Erlang citing its use in Facebook and Whatsapp. I salute Erlang for being scalable, but also want to technically justify its scalability.

Even if I find answers to these queries on an existing link, that will help.

Regards,

Yash

Comment: Great questions, but off topic for this site. Did you consider the mailing list? http://erlang.org/mailman/listinfo/erlang-questions

Answer (score 0):

Shortly:

- It's unmutable. You have no variables, only terms, tuples and atoms. Program execution can be divided by breakpoint at any place. Fully transactional model.
- Processes are even lightweight than .NET threads and isolated.
- It's made for communications. Millions of connections? Fully asynchronous? Maximum thread safety? Big cross-platform environment, which built only for one purpose — scale&communicate? It's all Ericsson language — first in this sphere.

You can choose some impersonators like F#, Scala/Akka, Haskell — they are trying to copy features from Erlang, but only Erlang born from and born for only one purpose — telecom.

Answers to other questions you can find on erlang.com and I'm suggesting you to visit handbook. Erlang built for other aims, so it's not for every task, and if you asking about awful things like php, Erlang will not be your language.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Erlang developer (yet) but from what I have read about it some of the features that makes it very scalable is that Erlang has its own lightweight processes that are using message passing to communicate with each other. Because of this there is no such thing as shared state and locking which is the case when using for example a multi threaded Java application.

Another difference compared to Java is that the Erlang VM does garbage collection on every little process that is running which does not take any time at all compared to Java which does garbage collection only per VM.

If you get problem with bottlenecks from database connection you could start by using a database pooling app running against maybe a replicated PostgreSQL cluster or if you still have bottlenecks use a multi replicated NoSQL setup with Mnesia, Riak or CouchDB.

I think process restarts can be very useful when you are experiencing rare bugs that only appear randomly and only when specific criteria is fulfilled. Bugs that cause the application to crash as soon as you restart the app should optimally be fixed or taken care of with a circuit breaker so that it does not spread further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way process restart helps.  By not having to deal with all possible error cases.  Say you have a program that divides numbers.  Some guy enters a zero to divide by.  Instead of checking for that possible error (and tons more), just code the "happy case" and let process crash when he enters 3/0.  It just restarts, and he can figure out what he did wrong.

You an extend this into an infinite number of situations (attempting to read from a non-existent file because the user misspelled it, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The big reason for process restart being valuable is that not every error happens every time, and checking that it worked is verbose.

Error handling is verbose typically, so writing it interspersed with the logic handling doing a task can make it harder to understand the code. Moving that logic outside of the task allows you to more clearly distinguish between "doing things" code, and "it broke" code.    You just let the thing that had a problem fail, and handle it as needed by a supervising party.

Since most errors don't mean that the entire program must stop, only that that particular thing isn't working right, by just restarting the part that broke, you can keep operating in a state of degraded functionality, instead of being down, while you repair the problem.

It should also be noted that the failure recovery is bounded. You have to lay out the limits for how much failure in a certain period of time is too much. If you exceed that limit, the failure propagates to another level of supervision. Each restart includes doing any needed process initialization, which is sometimes enough to fix the problem. For example, in dev, I've accidentally deleted a database file associated with a process. The crashes cascaded up to the level where the file was first created, at which point the problem rectified itself, and everything carried on.